# How does GridBagLayout determine size of container

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I am using a JDialog with GridBagLayout. Since this layout determines the container and component size automatically, I have not used setSize on anything. However, when the GUI is drawn, it seems to be stretching the container unnecessarily.

Why does GridBagLayout not size the container to "just as much as needed"? Basically I want the dialog size to be just as big as the table inside. Here is the code snippet:

```
public class GridBagLayoutTester  
{

public static void main(String[] args)

{

JDialog mDialog = new JDialog();

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    // Create a table to be added to the panel
    JTable table = new JTable(4,4);
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
    scrollpane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.ORANGE, 5));

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;

    // Add table to the panel
    panel1.add(scrollpane, gbc);

    mDialog.add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Display the window.
    mDialog.pack();
    mDialog.setVisible(true);
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the preferred size of components when the default sizing isn't what you want.

Change your program to add these lines:

```
    // Display the window.
    mDialog.pack();
    Dimension d = table.getPreferredSize();
    d.width += 16;
    d.height += 10;
    scrollpane.setPreferredSize(d);
    mDialog.pack();
    mDialog.setVisible(true);
```

The additional width of 16 accommodates the border and vertical scroll bar.

The additional height of 10 accommodates the border.